# How can I get RXJS throttleTime to enable both leading and trailing while preventing requests in quick succession

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6

I basically want to use thottleTime except I don't want to ever enable 2 notifications to be run in quick succession. It seems that throttletime basically resets its timer after it completes a "trailing" notificaiton.

So for source notifications (where each character is separated by 1000ms)

`-AB---C----`

So assuming usage `thottleTime(3000, asyncScheduler, { leading: true, trailing: true })`, this will push notifications:

`-A---BC----`

(aka it fires the leading 'A', and the trailing 'B' 3 seconds later which is what I want, however it immediately fires the next 'C' as it is a new leading notification.

What I really want is:

`-A---B---C-`

In summary, how can I get an operator that:

1. Immediately fires on first notification
2. Waits X amount of time minimum before firing the next noficiation.
3. ONLY immediately fires a third notification if it is at least X amount of time after the 2nd.

I have seen various other options on SO that meet (1) and (2), but none that meet (3) also.

Comment: Can you reproduce the example, cause afaik `throttleTime` should also trigger a X waiting period after the trailing notification.

Comment: Oh really! Maybe something else more dubious is going on. I will try reproduce the case - thanks.

Comment: @akotech is right, there must be something else going on where you're witnessing the discrepancy. I can't reproduce your problem either: https://playcode.io/1322183

Comment: Thankyou for helping with that reproduction @akotech, it made it abundantly clear to me it normally works as I expected it should. For whatever reason my usage in redux-observable (hard to create a full reproducible case), behaved quite differently. Stranger still using `throttle(() => interval(3000), { leading: true, trailing: true })` seemed to solve my problem, I would love to know why but suspect I never will understand the difference. For reference I am using "rxjs": "^6.5.5", "redux-observable": "^1.2.0", "redux": "^4.0.5".